# Excel VBA - OT Hours span two pay periods - how to auto calculate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I can't find anything in the archives of answered questions that addressed this.
I'm pretty good with Excel but this is frustrating me.
I've been tasked with improving the tool that our office staff uses to track regular hours, OT hours, and various paid leave.
I have a great start on the whole thing but because the company pay periods are bimonthly (1st to 15th and 16th to EOM) I'm running into difficulty **automatically** calculating the OT hours to pay when the work week (for the OT) spans two pay periods.
I have a column that shows the day of the week (Monday = 2, Tuesday =3, etc.) and I was trying to figure out how to look at the Day column and calculate all instances of Day2-Day6 hours to get OT hours (if any-I have a formula for that)to pay in the current pay period. I need to look backwards at the beginning of a new pay period if the new pay period does not start on Monday.
The spreadsheet has the prior pay period as well as the current pay period laid out.
I would sure appreciate any advice.
Have a lovely day - Lynda

Here is the data:

```
DayofWeek; Date; StartTime; EndTime; Lunch; Hours@Work; FringeType; FringeHours; TotalPayHours; WeeklyOTHrs (these are the column headers)
5 Thursday, March 16, 2017 7:30 17:00 1 8.50 8.50 
6 Friday, March 17, 2017 8:00 16:30 0.5 8.00 8.00 12.00 
2 Monday, March 20, 2017 7:30 17:00 1 8.50 H 8 16.50 
3 Tuesday, March 21, 2017 8:10 16:30 1 7.33 7.33 
4 Wednesday, March 22, 2017 8:00 17:00 1 8.00 V 8 16.00 
5 Thursday, March 23, 2017 8:00 17:30 0.5 9.00 9.00 
6 Friday, March 24, 2017 7:40 17:00 1 8.33 8.33 1.17
```

I now have a formula in the OT cells:

```
=IF($B30=6,IF(SUM(G26:G30)>40,SUM(G26:G30)-40,""),"")
```

Comment: Hi Lynda, can you include some data and what you expect your output to look like in your question please? If we can recreate your problem then we should be able to help :)

Comment: Day of Week Date Start Time End Time Lunch Hours @ Work Fringe Type Fringe Hours Total Pay Hours Weekly OT Hrs
5 Thursday, March 16, 2017 7:30 17:00 1 8.50   8.50 
6 Friday, March 17, 2017 8:00 16:30 0.5 8.00   8.00 12.00
2 Monday, March 20, 2017 7:30 17:00 1 8.50 H 8 16.50 
3 Tuesday, March 21, 2017 8:10 16:30 1 7.33   7.33 
4 Wednesday, March 22, 2017 8:00 17:00 1 8.00 V 8 16.00 
5 Thursday, March 23, 2017 8:00 17:30 0.5 9.00   9.00 
6 Friday, March 24, 2017 7:40 17:00 1 8.33   8.33 1.17
I have now a formula in the OT cells: =IF($B30=6,IF(SUM(G26:G30)>40,SUM(G26:G30)-40,""),"")

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to paste in a table.

Comment: Just edit your original question to add the data - I can edit it to format better if needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options that might be helpful, both use the SUMIFS function. The first option needs less code, but requires that the start and end dates of the respective period are defined in cells outside the data table.

**Option 1.**
If you're *only* interested in the total for each pay period, you could skip the OT column and instead calculate the total outside the data table. Here's an example with only 3 columns. In the screenshot, B5 contains the following formula:

```
    =SUMIFS($C$12:$C$33,$A$12:$A$33,">="&$B$3,$A$12:$A$33,"<="&$B$4)
```

SUMIFS sums all values in column C if they are within the dates of the previous period as specified in cells B3 and B4.

Similarly, B9 contains a formula for the current period, as defined by cells B7 and B8:

```
   =SUMIFS($C$12:$C$33,$A$12:$A$33,">="&$B$7,$A$12:$A$33,"<="&$B$8)
```

[image: Total sums separate from data table. Static date reference.]

**Option 2.** 
If you want to track *accumulated* OT hours in each period, you can keep the OT column and add a variation of the formula above. In this example I have included two extra columns to define the start and end of the period (this makes the formula prettier; if you don't want extra columns, these formulas can be incorporated into the formula in column D).

In this screenshot, D3 contains the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C3,$A$3:$A3,">="&E3,$A$3:$A3,"<="&F3)
```

This is essentially the same formula as in option 1, but the range increases for each row, so that D4 contains:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C4,$A$3:$A4,">="&E3,$A$3:$A4,"<="&F3)
```

Also, the start and end dates of the period are dynamic and contained in columns E and F. The formulas check if the current date is in the first or second half of the month, and adjust the start and end dates accordingly.

Start date (cell E3):

```
=IF(A3<=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),15),DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),1),DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),16))
```

End date (cell F3):

```
=IF(A3<=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),15),DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),15),EOMONTH(A3,0))
```

[image: Accumulated total. Dynamic date references.]

Note: If you want to avoid extra columns, you can incorporate columns E and F into D, so that cell D3 would contain:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C3,$A$3:$A3,">="&IF(A3<=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),15),DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),1),DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),16)),$A$3:$A3,"<="&IF(A3<=DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),15),DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3),15),EOMONTH(A3,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply.  I will take a look at both of these options and let you know how I fare!

Comment: Note that I've tested this only on a non-English version of Excel; the formulas above are manually translated, so beware of possible typos if you run into trouble.